# How to setup mysql (@Ubuntu-Server) auto connect to other host?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I am using Ubuntu-server. Can I setup / configure 'mysql' to auto-connect to another host? I mean if I type mysql on my terminal, it will connect automatically  to specific host.

Thanks.

Comment: Just make a shell-script with the correct options like `--host` and such.

Comment: So you actually want a command-line script to run on demand, not really automatic. Right?

Comment: @yakobom  i mean can i set default hostname ??? so when i type mysql on my terminal it default connect to sepicific IP..

Comment: @tadman yes, i mean i want to set default host... so i didnt need to use -h on mysql command

Comment: I suggested an alternative before seeing your comment - to set an alias for the specific db. Hope it helps.

Comment: You could try hacking around with your [`my.cnf` file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) under the `[client]` section, but keep in mind this is highly unusual. You'll probably have to create a shell wrapper or alias to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts for the answer.

First - how to make an alias, a word that if you type it, a specific command will execute (taken from [here](http://blog.revathskumar.com/2012/02/create-command-alias-in-ubuntu.html):

1. Create ~/.bash_aliases if not exists
2. touch ~/.bash_aliases
3. Open ~/.bash_aliases in a editor and append alias MY_COMMAND_ALIAS="THE COMMAND YOU WANT"
   or use command echo 'alias MY_COMMAND_ALIAS="THE COMMAND YOU WANT"' >> ~/.bash_aliases
   Save it
4. Use reload source ~/.bash_profile command to reload profile or reopen the terminal

Second part - the command you want to run mysql command, it will be something like:

```
mysql -u $user -p$passsword -Bse "command1;command2;....;commandn"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple wrapper like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/mysql --user $MYSQL_USER -p $MYSQL_PASSWORD --host $MYSQL_HOST $*
```

Where that should work almost identically to the default `mysql` command with a few tiny exceptions, like how `LOAD DATA INFILE` will read files *only* on the server, not your local machine.

You may need to do the same for `mysqldump` and other related commands like `mysqladmin` if you use those.

Be sure to specify the *actual* path to the `mysql` binary you want to run. I'm using `/usr/bin/mysql` here but it could be something else.